# Sending Data from an iOS App to an HTTPS Service

Tags: ios, web-services, encryption, xamarin, https

I have developed an iOS app using Xamarin and I am unsure about how encryption would work when calling a service that uses HTTPS.

On my end I do nothing particularly special: I utilize a RestClient and add the credentials to the body of a json serialized request. I then post it to the HTTPS service.

Is this safe or should I be doing more? I am not sure if iOS handles the rest for me in terms of encryption.

Comment: You are using SSL and I would ***assume*** TLS version 1.2 (you did not specific which version of iOS), so the question back to you what are your concerns? MITM exploits can be handled via cert pinning within your app (or better, using the sha256 hashes of the certs (primary/secondary/backups/...), Do you control the server's cert? What is the rotation policy of it? etc...

Answer (score 0):

When using HTTPS everything except the server address is encrypted during transit. The encryption is totally transparent to the client and server.

Example: for the URL `https://myApiEndpoint.com/getIsUserValid/user123/password123‌​4` only `myApiEndpoint.com` is not encrypted, the rest of the URL is encrypted.

In order to protect against [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attacks pin the server certificate, that is verify that the certificate received on the request belongs to the correct server.

If you control the server use TLS 1.2 and Perfect Forward Secrecy.

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

Yes, by using `HTTPS`, you are most-likely safe. However, there are a couple things to verify to ensure that there are no security leaks.

#### More Info on TLS

Communication with secure `HTTPS` enpoints encrypt the header and body of the message by default using TLS.

> HTTPS consists of communication over Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) within a connection encrypted by Transport Layer Security. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS)

## Things To Verify

#### Do Not Use Sensitve Data in the URL

The Url of the `HTTPS` endpoint is *not* encrypted. It is important to never put any sensitive data into the Url of the `HTTPS` enpoint. To ensure sensitive data is encrpyted, put the data in the message body.

For example, if you are validating a user's login (username: user1234, password: password1234), do not send the username/password as a url parameter. Instead, serialize the username and password data, and set it as the `HttpContent` of the `HttpClient`.

**Bad:** `https://myApiEndpoint.com/getIsUserValid/user123/password1234`

#### iOS HttpClient Implementation

Ensure that you are using `NSUrlSession` for the iOS HttpClient Implementation.

`NSUrlSession` will use `TLS` by default when communicating with secure `HTTPS` endpoints. As of iOS 10, `NSAppTransportSecurity` will not allow communication to  non-secure `HTTP` endpoints by default; communication with non-secure `HTTP` enpoints can be enabled by updating `NSAppTransportSecurity` in  `Info.plist`, [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33).

You can verify `NSUrlSession` is being used in the iOS Build Settings (screenshot below).

[image: iOSHttpClient]

Comment: "The Url of the HTTPS endpoint is not encrypted " This is a generalization and not true. The host domain name is not encrypted but any directory path and/or querry string are encrypted. Example: for the URL `https://myApiEndpoint.com/getIsUserValid/user123/password1234` only `myApiEndpoint.com` is not encrypted, the rest of the URL is. There is a consideration: the entire URL may be logged on the server.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @zaph! That’s good to know! Do you have a link where I can I read up more on this? I searched all over for more info on this a few months ago and couldn’t find anything on it!

Comment: Also if the certificate is not pinned a MITM attack is possible. One current scenario is on a location (coffee shop) that has free WiFi an attacker can put up another access point that users may end up connected to. Many devices will automatically select an access point automatically, I even had this happen at home when a new neighbor installed WiFi without a password.

Comment: See on wikipedia [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS0) starting at: "*Because HTTPS piggybacks HTTP entirely on top of TLS, the **entirety of the underlying HTTP protocol can be encrypted**.*"